# IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds (iloc[1: , :])

Tags: python, pandas, indexoutofboundsexception

This will be tricky, but I need your help. To sum up, my coworker in charge of data left, and there is an unsolved bug in his Python requests. I have close to 0 knowledge of this language, and I didn't write these Python requests, so I can't figure out the issue. Here is the code:

```py
churn_list = []
for i in Version:
  churn_temp = churn_data[churn_data['Version']==i].sort_values('Level').reset_index()
  churn_temp = churn_temp.iloc[1: , :]
  **churn_temp = churn_calculation(churn_temp)**

  # Plotting Churn
  ##
  import plotly.graph_objects as go
  fig = go.Figure()
  fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=churn_temp[churn_temp['Level']<15]['Level'], 
                      y=churn_temp[churn_temp['Level']<15]['Churn_perc'],
                      name="drop off in %"))
  fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=churn_temp[churn_temp['Level']<15]['Level'], 
                          y=churn_temp[churn_temp['Level']<15]['Cumulative_Churn_perc'],
                          name="Cumulative drop off in %"))
  fig.update_layout(
      autosize=False,
      width=1000,
      height=500,
      template='simple_white',
      title_text='Churn Visualisation for version '+i,
      yaxis_title="drop off in %",
      xaxis_title="Level",
      title_x=0.5)
  
  fig.show()
  churn_list.append(churn_temp)
```

It's a code to calculate churn, based on a BigQuery request. It worked fine in the first days, and then this happened out of the blue. The error is at `churn_temp = churn_calculation(churn_temp)`. Here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-ddc2b4335820> in <module>()
      3   churn_temp = churn_data[churn_data['Version']==i].sort_values('Level').reset_index()
      4   churn_temp = churn_temp.iloc[1: , :]
----> 5   churn_temp = churn_calculation(churn_temp)
      6 
      7   # Plotting Churn

5 frames
<ipython-input-56-4b23d0a07bff> in churn_calculation(df)
      4   df.loc[:,'Cumulative Churn']=df.loc[:,'Chrun'].expanding(1).sum()
      5   df.loc[:,'Churn_perc']=round((df.loc[:,'Chrun']/df.loc[:,'Players'])*100,2)
----> 6   df.loc[:,'Cumulative_Churn_perc']=round((df.loc[:,'Cumulative Churn']/df.iloc[0,3])*100,2)
      7   return df

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    923                 with suppress(KeyError, IndexError):
    924                     return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
--> 925             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
    926         else:
    927             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1504     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: tuple):
   1505 
-> 1506         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   1507         with suppress(IndexingError):
   1508             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    752         for i, k in enumerate(key):
    753             try:
--> 754                 self._validate_key(k, i)
    755             except ValueError as err:
    756                 raise ValueError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   1407             return
   1408         elif is_integer(key):
-> 1409             self._validate_integer(key, axis)
   1410         elif isinstance(key, tuple):
   1411             # a tuple should already have been caught by this point

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_integer(self, key, axis)
   1498         len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
   1499         if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 1500             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
   1501 
   1502     # -------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Can someone help me on that matter? I searched similar issues, but it's not quite the same so I didn't find the solution. I tried to replace the current "churn_temp.iloc[1: , :]" with the exact number of columns and rows of the databse, but it didn't fix the issue.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `churn_calculation` method

```py
----> 6   df.loc[:,'Cumulative_Churn_perc']=round((df.loc[:,'Cumulative Churn']/df.iloc[0,3])*100,2)
```

Here you use `df.iloc[0,3]`, `iloc` indexing starts from 0, the problem might be that your `df` is empty or `df` doesn't have 4 columns.

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton for your answer! 
Df designates the data structure, right? I mean the table data it's supposed to take data from?
If the issue is that's empty, it could mean it takes from the wrong database?

Comment: I changed it (I put the exact number of colulns of the database), but I still have the error

Comment: @Justine What's the output of `df.shape`?

Comment: Mh I don't see "df.shape" :/ Should it be in the code error? I checked and df.shape is nowhere.

Comment: Oh, I think it's (0,7)

Comment: @Justine There is no rows in your df, iloc[0,3] means take the first row and the fourth column. Since there is no rows, so first row would throw error.